# PostgreSQL query select records with highest count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table we will call `authors`.

`authors` has many `blog_posts` and has many `articles`.

Both `blog_posts` and `articles` have a column `state`

I need to write a query that gets the top `x` amount of `authors` by the highest total `blog_posts` and `articles` combined where the `state` is equal to `open`

I've come up with this so far

```
WITH blog_post_count AS (
    SELECT author_id, count(id) as num_open_blog_posts
    FROM  blog_posts
    WHERE state = 'open'
    GROUP BY author_id
),
article_count AS (
    SELECT author_id, count(id) as num_open_articles
    FROM articles
    WHERE state = 'open'
    GROUP BY author_id
)
SELECT *, (
            CASE WHEN num_open_blog_posts IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE num_open_blog_posts END
            + CASE WHEN num_open_articles IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE num_open_articles END) as total_postings
    FROM authors
    LEFT OUTER JOIN blog_post_count ON blog_post_count.author_id = authors.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN article_count ON article_count.author_id = authors.id 
    ORDER BY total_postings DESC
    LIMIT 25 -- could be any value
```

^works but I'm sure it could be improved alot

Answer (score 0):

How about using `UNION ALL` ?

```sql
WITH total_post_count AS (
  SELECT 
    author_id
  FROM  
    blog_posts
  WHERE 
    state = 'open'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    author_id
  FROM 
    articles
  WHERE 
    state = 'open'
)
SELECT 
  author_id,
  count(*) as total_posts
FROM 
  total_post_count
GROUP BY 
  author_id
ORDER BY 
  total_posts DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: is this supposed to be more performant?

Comment: I am not sure, you can check execution plans of both these queries. 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html#:~:text=The%20ANALYZE%20option%20causes%20the,of%20rows%20it%20actually%20returned.